# How to write a lazy, variable argument version of "orElse"

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, lazy-evaluation

Is it possible to write a generalised `orElse` method from `Option` that takes a variable number of arguments? That is, instead of:

```
lazy val o1 = { println("foo"); None }
lazy val o2 = { println("bar"); Some("bar") }
lazy val o3 = { println("baz"); Some("baz") } 
// ...
o1 orElse o2 orElse o3 // orElse ...
```

You could use:

```
orElse(o1, o2, o3) //, ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [The Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (4.6 Function Declarations and Definitions) you cannot define varargs by-name parameters:

```
ParamType ::= Type
| ‘=>’ Type
| Type ‘*’

scala> def orElse(x : (=> String)*)
<console>:1: error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
       def orElse(x : (=> String)*)
```

You could replace the lazy arg with function and an implicit type conversion:

```
def orElse[T](x : (()=> Option[T])*) : Option[T] = 
    if(x.isEmpty) None else x.first.apply.orElse(orElse((x drop 1) :_*))
implicit def anyToFun0[T](t : => T) : (() => T) = () => t
orElse(o1, o2, o3)
```

Comment: I tried this at the repl, but unfortunately it appears to force all three arguments.

Comment: You're right the implicit type conversion forced the evaluation. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the question a bit late :). One possibility is to wrap `=> A` into a helper class together with a helper function to simplify its creation:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class Helper[+A](value: => A) extends Function0[A] {
  override def apply(): A = value;
}
object Helper {
  def unapply[A](h: Helper[A]): Option[A] = Some(h());
}
implicit def toHelper[A](body: => A) = new Helper(body);
```

The extractor isn't required, it just allows easy matching on the helper. Then we can write

```
def orElse[A](xs: Helper[Option[A]]*): Option[A] =
  xs.collectFirst[A]({
    case Helper(Some(r)) => r;
  })

lazy val o1 = { println("foo"); None }
lazy val o2 = { println("bar"); Some("bar") }
lazy val o3 = { println("baz"); Some("baz") }

orElse(o1, o2, o3) //, ...
```

This is just a simplified solution, a more realistic one would be

```
def orElse[A](x: Option[A], xs: Helper[Option[A]]*): Option[A]
```

with a more efficient implementation.

---

There already is a class similar to `Helper`  in Scalaz, called `Name` with implementation `Need` that ensures that the body is evaluated at most once. So with Scalaz, it could be implemented as

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scalaz._
import scalaz.Scalaz._

implicit def toNeed[A](body: => A): Name[A] = Need(body);

def orElse[A](xs: Name[Option[A]]*): Option[A] =
  xs.collectFirst[A]({
    case Name(Some(r)) => r;
  })

lazy val o1 = { println("foo"); None }
lazy val o2 = { println("bar"); Some("bar") }
lazy val o3 = { println("baz"); Some("baz") }

orElse(o1, o2, o3) //, ...
```