# A light weight Scala fork join syntax

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, fork-join

Despite the upcoming java 7 standard fork/join framework, I am building some helper method that is light weight in syntax for client to run code in parallel.
Here is a runnable main method to illustrate the idea.

```
import actors.Futures

object ForkTest2 {



  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    test1
    test2
  }



  def test1 {
    val (a, b, c) =fork({
      Thread.sleep(500)
      println("inside fx1 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      true
    }, {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("inside fx2 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      "stringResult"
    }, {
      Thread.sleep(1500)
      println("inside fx3 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      1
    })

    println(b, a, c)
    true
  }

  def test2 {
    val results = forkAll({
      () =>
              Thread.sleep(500)
              println("inside fx1 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
              true
    }, {
      () =>
              Thread.sleep(1000)
              println("inside fx2 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
              "stringResult"
    }, {
      () =>
              Thread.sleep(1500)
              println("inside fx3 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
              1
    }, {
      () =>
              Thread.sleep(2000)
              println("inside fx4 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
              1.023
    })

    println(results)
    true
  }

  val tenMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 10

  def fork[A, B, C](
          fx1: => A,
          fx2: => B,
          fx3: => C
          ) = {
    val re1 = Futures.future(fx1)
    val re2 = Futures.future(fx2)
    val re3 = Futures.future(fx3)
    //default wait 10 minutes
    val result = Futures.awaitAll(tenMinutes, re1, re2, re3)
    (
            result(0).asInstanceOf[Option[A]],
            result(1).asInstanceOf[Option[B]],
            result(2).asInstanceOf[Option[C]]

            )
  }

  type fxAny = () => Any

  def forkAll(
          fx1: fxAny*
          ): List[Any] = {
    val results = fx1.toList.map {fx: fxAny => Futures.future(fx())}
    Futures.awaitAll(tenMinutes, results: _*)
  }
}
```

a sample out put is

```
(inside fx1 ,1263804802301)
(inside fx2 ,1263804802801)
(inside fx3 ,1263804803301)
(Some(stringResult),Some(true),Some(1))
(inside fx1 ,1263804803818)
(inside fx2 ,1263804804318)
(inside fx3 ,1263804804818)
(inside fx4 ,1263804805318)
List(Some(true), Some(stringResult), Some(1), Some(1.023))
```

test 1 illustrate a type safe return type

test 2 illustrate a arbitrary input argument

I hope to combine the two test method so the client code can run arbitrary function in parallel with type safe return type.

Another point about the arbitrary function arguments is:

I think the line

```
  type fxAny = () => Any
```

should really be code as

```
  type fxAny =  => Any
```

, but the scala compiler do not allow me to do so.

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric Torreborre wrote in the link provided by @retronym:

```
trait LazyParameters { 
  /** transform a value to a zero-arg function returning that value */ 
  implicit def toLazyParameter[T](value: =>T) = new LazyParameter(() => value) 
  /** class holding a value to be evaluated lazily */ 
  class LazyParameter[T](value: ()=>T) { 
    lazy val v = value() 
    def apply() = v 
  } 
}
```

Here's LazyParameter version of your test:

```
object ForkTest2 extends LazyParameters {
```

...

```
def forkAll(fx1: LazyParameter[Any]*): List[Any] = {
  val results = fx1.toList.map {
    fx: LazyParameter[Any] => Futures.future(fx.apply())}
  Futures.awaitAll(tenMinutes, results: _*)
}
```

**Edit**: As you've noticed, implicit evaluates the by-name parameter and it doesn't carry forward the evaluation delay. Why not just use the word `future`? I personally think it makes the code more readable.

```
import actors.Futures
import actors.Futures.future
import actors.Future
```

...

```
def test2 {
  val results = forkAll(
    future {
      Thread.sleep(500)
      println("inside fx1 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      true
    },
    future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("inside fx2 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      "stringResult"
    },
    future {
      Thread.sleep(1500)
      println("inside fx3 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      1
    },
    future {
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      println("inside fx4 ",+System.currentTimeMillis)
      1.023
    })

  println(results)
  true
}
```

...

```
def forkAll(futures: Future[Any]*): List[Any] = {
  println("forkAll")
  Futures.awaitAll(tenMinutes, futures: _*)
}
```

Comment: You can define this even shorter: implicit def anyToFun0[T](t : => T) : (() => T) = () => t (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826145/how-to-write-a-lazy-variable-argument-version-of-orelse/1826794#1826794). The problem is that you won't safe too much. You have to define a function or lazy val a block would be evaluated.

Comment: the implicit function would cause the fx be early evaluated and invoked. Client must explicit call the type conversion to prevent early evaluation

Answer (score 2):

You can't use call-by-name types as a repeated parameter (aka varargs), thanks to this bug: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/237

See recent discussion here: http://old.nabble.com/Lazy-varargs-td27169264.html

Answer (score 0):

A sample implementation for anyone interested,

For use case that with a few function argument, may be just define list of fork function with different number of arguments (following the idea in tuple definition) 
and enjoy type safe return type

```
object ForkTest4 extends LazyParameters {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    test4
  }

  def test4 {
    println("Begin test 4")
    //Without the explicit call to type conversion would cause early evaluation
    //    val result4 = forkAll({
    val result4 = forkAll(l {
      Thread.sleep(500)
      println("inside fx4 ", +System.currentTimeMillis)
      true
    })
    println(result4)
    true
  }

  val tenMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 10

  def forkAll(fx1: (() => Any)*): List[Any] = {

    val results = fx1.toList.map {

      fx: (() => Any) => {

        val result = Futures.future(fx.apply())

        result
      }
    }
    Futures.awaitAll(tenMinutes, results: _*)
  }

  def l[T](t: => T): (() => T) = () => t

  implicit def implicitLazy[T](t: => T): (() => T) = () => t
}
```