# Scala Fork-Join-All With Multiple Generic Types and 1 Generic Unit of Work

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, apache-spark, scala-reflect

I'm attempting to write a method which accepts multiple generic types and takes as an argument a unit of work to execute.

The idea is that the unit of work is a common function that itself is generic. For the sake of example, let's say it's something like the following:

```
def loadModelRdd[T: TypeTag](sc: SparkContext): RDD[T] = {
  ...
}
```

loadModelRdd() will construct an RDD of the given type after some internal processing like loading the Model information, etc.

A prototype method I've been hacking on looks something like the following (non-working):

```
def forkAll[A : Manifest, B : Manifest](work: => RDD[_]): (RDD[A], RDD[B]) = {
  def aFuture = Future { work } // How can I notify that this work call returns type A?
  def bFuture = Future { work } // How can I notify that this work call returns type B?

  val res = for {
    a <- aFuture
    b <- bFuture
  } yield (a.asInstanceOf[A], b.asInstanceOf[B])

  Await.result(res, 10.seconds)
}
```

This is a shortened version of the code I'm working on as I'm actually looking at accepting as many as 10 different types.

As you can see, the overall goal of the forkAll method is to wrap the unit of work in a Future, fork-join the execution of the unit of work for each type, then return the results as a Tuple'd result. An example consumer statement would be:

```
val (a, b) = forkAll[ClassA, ClassB](loadModelRdd)
```

i.e I want to fork-join at this point and wait for the results, but I want the executions to be executed in parallel and then collected back to the Driver (Spark Driver to be specific).

The problem is I'm not sure how to coerce the type returned by the unit of work within forkAll when constructing the Future {} blocks. Without the forkAll, the implementation looked like the following:

```
val resA = loadModelRdd[ClassA](sc)
val resB = loadModelRdd[ClassB](sc)
...
```

I am looking at doing this for two reasons:

1. To abstract the details of fork-join for any unit of work which matches this model.
2. A version of this code, which explicitly states what the unit of work is, is working in Production and was responsible for cutting execution of a long-running block by close to half. I have a couple of execution steps where this pattern could be applied

Is this something that is possible in Scala's type system? Or should I look at this problem from a different perspective? I've tried a couple of implementations (including one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084813/a-light-weight-scala-fork-join-syntax)) but I haven't quite found one that fits my current view of the problem

Please let me know if there is any additional information needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** [Scala does not allow *functions* with type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/513397), so what you want is not exactly possible.

You are attempting to pass a method with a type parameter. Although *methods* are allowed to have type parameters, *functions* are not. When you try to pass a method, it acts like an anonymous function, so you must specify a type.

However, since methods do allow type parameters, you can take advantage of this by creating an abstract class that will do your fork/join

```
abstract class ForkJoin {

  protected def work[T]: RDD[T]

  def apply[A, B]: (RDD[A], RDD[B]) = {
    // Write implementation of fork/join here
    (work[A], work[B])
  }
}
```

then overriding the type generic `work` method so that it does what you want, such as calling some other pre-defined method.

```
val forkJoin = new ForkJoin {
  override protected def work[T]: RDD[T] =
    loadModelRdd[T](sc)
}

val (intRdd, stringRdd) = forkJoin[Int, String]
```

Check out [this](https://gist.github.com/anishpatel/2dcd54f96781567c5248) for a prototype implementation that compiles and runs without issues.